# mpi dot product using point to point operations fails when data is large

Tags: mpi

I have below code two get a dot product of two vectors of size `VECTORSIZE`. Code works fine until `VECTORSIZE` up to 10000 but then it gives unrelated results. When I tried to debug the program I have seen that processor 0 (root) finishes its job before all processors send their local results. I got the same situation when I utilized the `MPI_Reduce()` (code part 2). However if I use `MPI_Scatter()` before `MPI_Reduce()` it is OK.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define VECTORSIZE 10000000
#define ROOT 0


//[[## operation ConstructVectorPart()
void ConstructVector(double * vector, int size, short vectorEnu)
{
  int i = 0;
    if(vectorEnu == 1) // i.e vector 1
    {
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            vector[i] = 0.1 + (i%20)*0.1;
        }
    }
    else if(vectorEnu == 2) // i.e. vector 2
    {
        for(i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
        {
            vector[i] = 2-(i%20)*0.1;
        }
    }
}

//[[## operation dotproduct()
double dotproduct(double* a, double* b, int length) 
{
  double result = 0;
    int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i<length; i++)
        result +=  a[i] * b[i];

  return result;
}

int main( argc, argv )
int  argc;
char **argv;
{
  int processorID, numofProcessors;
    int partialVectorSize ;
    double t1, t2, localDotProduct, result;

  MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
  MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numofProcessors );
  MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &processorID );

    if(processorID == 0)
        t1 = MPI_Wtime();

    // all processors constitute their own vector parts and 
    // calculates corresponding partial dot products
    partialVectorSize = VECTORSIZE/ numofProcessors;


    double *v1, *v2;
    v1 = (double*)(malloc((partialVectorSize) * sizeof(double)));
    v2 = (double*)(malloc((partialVectorSize) * sizeof(double)));

    ConstructVectorPart(v1,0,partialVectorSize,1);
    ConstructVectorPart(v2,0,partialVectorSize,2);

    localDotProduct = dotproduct(v1,v2, partialVectorSize);

    printf(" I am processor %d \n",processorID);

//----------------- code part 1 ---------------------------------------------   
    if( processorID != 0 ) // if not a master
    { // send partial result to master
        MPI_Send( &localDotProduct, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    }
    else // master
    {  // collect results
      result = localDotProduct; // own result
        int j;
        for( j=1; j<numofProcessors; ++j )
        {
            MPI_Recv( &localDotProduct, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, j, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            result += localDotProduct;
        }
        t2 = MPI_Wtime();
        printf(" result = %f  TimeConsumed = %f \n",result, t2-t1);
    }
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    /*
   //--------------------- code part 2 ----------------
  MPI_Reduce(&localDotProduct, &result, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(processorID == 0)
    {
            t2 = MPI_Wtime();
            printf(" result = %f  TimeConsumed = %f \n",result, t2-t1);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------
    */

    MPI_Finalize();

        free(v1);
        free(v2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is it doing that's incorrect? When I run the code locally (ignoring all of the dot product computation since it's not MPI), I don't get any problems with 4 processes.

Comment: I could not actually understand why you ignore dot product computation? Why isnt it mpi? execution gives correct dot product result until a reasonable vector sizes, then it fails,i.e, . gives wrong results. thanks for your interest.

Comment: I ignored it because there are no MPI calls in the dot product computation. What this means is that your MPI code most likely isn't the problem. It's probably coming from your computation of the dot product itself.